# How to grep inside while loop with two files or one file

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have this use case where I am trying to list some keys from s3 and filtering the results based on a grep command

`fileA - abc/def
        def/123`

After listing the keys, I am trying to remove this exact key from the list. For example, if list return 2 other keys with the same prefix

`list - abc/def/123
       abc/def/1234
       abc/ghi/12345
       def/123/456
       def/456/4567`

I want to remove the keys matching the pattern read from file i.e. `abc/def and def/123`

Code :

`while read line; do
  prefix = $(echo "$line"| grep -oPw '[A-Za-z0-9]*')
  aws s3api list-objects --bucket blah-bucket --prefix "$prefix" | grep -vFfw "$line" > result
done < fileA`

I am getting this error that `command not found : prefix`

What am I missing here in the loop?

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem that has been addressed in various questions posted here for years and years. :-)

The notation you want should look more like this:

```
prefix="$(echo ...)"
```

Remember that the shell is a *shell*, not really a full fledged programming language. Its parsing rules were intended to facilitate calling other programs, and setting up the plumbing to allow those programs to interact with each other.

Here are the various ways mis-placed spaces can be interpreted by shells in the Bourne family (sh, bash, ksh, zsh, ash/dash).  Consider:

```
var=val
var =val
var= val
var = val
```

- `var=val`: this is the correct syntax for variable assigment -- an unquoted word followed immediately by an equals followed immediately by an argument.
- `var =val`: this runs the `var` command with `=val` as its argument.
- `var= val`: this assigns an empty string to the `var` variable, then runs the `val` command as if `var` had been `export`ed to it. This is meant to provide single-use environment variables to commands called by the shell.
- `var = val`: this runs the `var` command with `=` and `val` as arguments.

Other (non-Bourne-style or non-POSIX) shells will have different interpretations.

Also, beware that you will be overwriting the file `result` for every iteration of this loop.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you had simple syntax error.  But, if I understand the what you mean by *remove the keys matching the pattern read from file*, you're working too hard.

If the following solution does what you want, I guarantee it will run faster and be easier to understand:

```
$ head patterns input
==> patterns <==
abc/def
def/123

==> input <==
abc/def/123
abc/def/1234
abc/ghi/12345
def/123/456
def/456/4567

$ grep -vf patterns input
abc/ghi/12345
def/456/4567
```

Any shell solution that iterates over the *data* is bound to be the wrong approach.  Look for ways to let **grep** and friends operate on whole files, and use the shell to choose the files.  It always a safe bet your problem can be solved that way, because over the decades lots of problems looked like your problem.  :-)

Comment: Yes that would work if you have the entire input in a file. In my case , I was trying to do it on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the following chain of commands:

```
$cat to_remove.in 
abc/def
def/123


$cat to_process.in 
abc/def/123
abc/def/1234
abc/ghi/12345
def/123/456
def/456/4567


$awk 'BEGIN{ORS="\\\\|"}{print}' to_remove.in | sed 's/\\|$//' | xargs -I {} grep -v {} to_process.in
abc/ghi/12345
def/456/4567
```

**Explanations:**

- `awk` will be used to create a regex from file `to_remove.in` with `|` between each line that will be used by `grep -v` to exclude the lines from file `to_process.in`
- `sed 's/\\|$//'` is used to remove the last `|` at the end of the regex string
- then you use `xargs` to pass the resulting regex string to your `grep` command

Comment: This would work as well for static inputs. I was trying to do it on the fly using the while loop. Though I think using xargs might make it a little faster